# When the user scrolls to a particular div alert the div id using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have four divs in my HTML.

```
<html>
<body>
   <div id="div1">aaaaa</div>
   <div id="div2">bbbb</div>
   <div id="div3">cccc</div>
   <div id="div4">dddd</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user start scrolling the page, whichever the div he see then it should alert or show the particular div id. Example: when he is seeing the content aaaa it should show or alert div1.

This has to be done using JavaScript only.

Comment: Have started wring your script ? If yes, do share it with us! If _NO_, start wring it...

Comment: you can use onFocus event on div. 
onFocus='myFunction(this);'

Comment: Closing as far too broad. Questions here should be accompanied by a genuine effort. Stack Overflow is not a resource where free work can be requested.

Answer (score 1):

**JS version of your answer:**

This will give you an alert when you scroll down to second div (orange background color)

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("div2");
    var hT = elem.offsetTop,
        hH = getAbsoluteHeight(elem),
        wH = window.innerHeight,
        wS = window.pageYOffset;
    if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
        alert('you have scrolled to the Div2!');
    }
}

function getAbsoluteHeight(el) {
  // Get the DOM Node if you pass in a string
  el = (typeof el === 'string') ? document.querySelector(el) : el; 

  var styles = window.getComputedStyle(el);
  var margin = parseFloat(styles['marginTop']) +
           parseFloat(styles['marginBottom']);

  return Math.ceil(el.offsetHeight + margin);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

#div2 {
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No, I need without using jquery plugin. Please see above you have used Jquery. Its not a right answer. Please help me to get in pure javascript @Mr.7

Comment: Sorry, i posted your code instead of mine. now i updated :)